# Is it possible to use Rack::Session middleware with async_sinatra?

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra, rack

Using `Rack::Session` in conjunction with `async_sinatra`'s `aroute` methods doesn't seem to be possible. I gather this is because `async_sinatra` raises `:async` before the session middleware has a chance to modify necessary headers, but this seems like a common problem. Is there any way to make this work without rewriting the session middleware? Am I overlooking something obvious?

```
require "sinatra/async"

class AsyncTest < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Async

  enable :sessions

  aget "/foo" do
    session[:message] = "Hello World!"
    body "foo: #{session[:message]}"
  end

  aget "/bar" do
    body "bar: #{session[:message]}"
  end

  run! if app_file == $0
end
```

Visiting `/foo` renders "foo: Hello World!" as expected, but `/bar` renders "bar: ", causing frowns all around town. What to do? Is this just impossible?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the session middleware before the `body` call:

```
aget "/bar" do
  message = session[:message]
  body "bar: #{message}"
end
```